# What happens when I give more parameters than required in the function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Assume -

```
function noname(a, b) {
//code
}
```

and I give -

```
noname(4,5,6,7);
```

What will happen then?

Comment: **Note:** The declared arguments have no effect on the way you call the function - you can even call it with no arguments at all.

Comment: more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002817/ok-to-invoke-a-js-function-with-more-arguments-than-it-formally-receives

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The additional parameters will simply get ignored.

They will however be available as part of the `arguments` pseudo-array, e.g. as `arguments[2]`, `arguments[3]`.

If you give *fewer* variables than are required then the missing ones will be `undefined`.

Comment: How does `sort` work then, when there usually are more items in the array than the functions? Is it an exception on arrays?

Comment: `sort` is a method _of_ an array - the array arrives in the `this` variable and is manipulated directly.  It's not passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As Alnitak said, they become `undefined` since they haven nothing binding them, unless as stated: `arguments[i]` is used`.

A good practice is to first test how many original parameters the function had stated by using the `.length` method available on all functions.

`noname.length === 2 // in your case`

This makes it easier to then save any additional arguments (just in case we might want to use them)

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9sg7/)

```
function noname (a, b) {
    console.log('Original parameters in this function: ' + noname.length);

    var additionalParameters = [];

    if (arguments.length > noname.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length - noname.length; i++) {
            // We need to start arguments off at index: 2 in our case
            // The first 0 & 1 parameters are a, b

            additionalParameters[i] = arguments[i + noname.length];
            // These of course will be saved starting at 0 index on additionalParameters
        }
    }

    console.log(additionalParameters);
}

noname(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

​

Comment: I wouldn't say that was specifically good practise, since many functions don't expose `.length`.  In any case, I'd use `var additional = [].prototype.slice.call(arguments, arguments.callee.length)` instead of that verbose (and incredibly inefficient) loop.